# In Tritium, How to insert any element between the children second and third anchor tag?

Tags: moovweb, tritium

```
 <div class="parent">
 <a class="cld1">1</a>
 <a  class="cld2">2</a> 
 <a  class="cld3" >3</a> 
 <a  class="cld4" >4</a>       
</div>
```

How to insert any element between the children second and third anchor tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('//div[@class="parent"]/a[@class="cld2"]') {
        insert_after('div','hii')
    }
```

You can do like this to inset div in between  tag
Refer http://tester.tritium.io/18f12697fde014066894af356915af1471782732

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is:

```
$('//div[@class="parent"]/a[position()=2]') {
    insert_after('div','Hello', class:'test')
    }
```

This way we need not to worry about enter code here the class change or text change also.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this if you want to target the number instead of the class is like so:

```
$('//div[@class="parent"]/a[contains(text(),"2")]') {
  insert_after('div', class:'example')        
}
```